# All you have to do now is "finish your homework" or "to finish your homework"?

Tags: to-infinitive

I know that the sentences below are both correct.

1. All you have to do is finish your homework.
2. All you have to do is to finish your homework.

My grammar book says that "to do is..." is an exception and you call place the base form of a verb write after "is" without "to".

However, I have a question here.  What if there's another word between "to do" and "is"?  For example,

3. All you have to do now is (to) finish your homework.
4. What you had to do yesterday was (to) finish your homework.

"Now" and "yesterday" are placed between "to do" and "is".  Is it still grammatical if you omit "to" in the two sentences, 3 and 4?

Comment: 3 and 4 are fine. Time adverbs can be put in a sentence in many places without changing the rest of the sentence. You could even add a more complex adverbial, although if it gets much more complex, then you would be more likely to include the "to".